# Contact selector on infopath form not displaying in email

Tags: infopath, email, outlook

This is something that has confused for some time.

If there is a contact selector on the form and the form gets sent in an email, the contact selector seems to become hidden. I have searched online but cannot seem to find a single person mentioning this. I have read that when viewing a form in Outlook it doesn't display correctly such as any field whose width is set to 100% stretches out beyond what it would look like in a browser. The information is not going away as it is accessible by going to the form.

Has anyone encountered this problem of contact selectors being hidden in emails before or is there something wrong with how I have the form set up? I would also like to know if there is a workaround such as displaying a field in its place that is only visible when the form is emailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I have seen this problem. It worked this way in 2010 as well when the form was actually displayed in the email. I'm not sure what phase you are sending the form in an email and why you are doing so, but in our case, we were having to send the completed form to an external vendor who would take action on it. What we ended up doing was actually taking and creating a second text box that just displayed the contents of the "DisplayName" in another field and after the lookup was made, we would switch to a view that would display this text box only. Then when you send the email, it is from that view and you do not have this problem.